# AngularJs and MVC API Controller don't get called

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-apicontroller

i have the following object

```
public class VeicoloDTO
{
    public string tipoVeicolo { get; set; }
    public string marcaVeicolo { get; set; }
    public string modello { get; set; }
    public string allestimento { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> cilindrata { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> massa { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> kilowat { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> cavalliFiscali { get; set; }
    public string targa { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dataPrimaImmatricolazione { get; set; }
    public string tipoAlimnetazione { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dataAcquisto { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> valoreVeicolo { get; set; }
    public string RIPARO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> numeroVeicoli { get; set; }
    public string dotazioni { get; set; }
    public string antifurto { get; set; }
    public string trasporto { get; set; }

}
```

and the following webApi controller

```
  public int PostDatiVeicolo(VeicoloDTO veicolo){
         .....
  }
```

And the follwing angularJs function POST

```
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/api/Pratica/PostDatiVeicolo',
            dataType: "json",
            params: { veicolo: JSON.stringify($scope.datiVeicolo) }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.idVeicolo = response.data;
            $scope.readyToView = true;
```

my jsonObject inside $scope.datiVeicolo is:

```
        {
        [functions]: ,
        __proto__: { },
        allestimento: "asd",
        antifurto: "meccanico",
        cavalliFiscali: 0,
        cilindrata: 0,
        dataAcquisto: [date] Fri Apr 22 2016 10:55:06 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale),
        dataPrimaImmatricolazione: [date] Fri Apr 22 2016 10:55:06 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale),
        dotazioni: "Abs",
        kilowat: 0,
        marcaVeicolo: "",
        massa: 0,
        modello: "asd",
        numeroVeicoli: null,
        riparo: "Garage",
        targa: "asd",
        tipoAlimnetazione: "Benzina",
        tipoVeicolo: "Auto",
        trasporto: "nessuno",
        valoreVeicolo: 0
      }
```

Comment: Do you have `[HttpPost]` attribute on your method?

Comment: you are not doing the correct POST

Comment: i see i have to remove "Controller" from   url: '/api/PraticaController/PostDatiVeicolo',

Comment: And FYI, that's an `Action` not the controller ;) So add  `[HttpPost]` above your action and check again. And @T-student : Yes you must not use the word `controller` with the controller name in your route

Comment: You know you should remove "Controller" and it's still there and you are nagging why this code is not working? @T-student

Comment: removing 'Controller' i get "the value can not be null.\r\n Parameter name entity"

Comment: if i remove the JSON.stringify($scope.datiVeicolo) to $scope.datiVeicolo , it go inside the controller but the Object is null ! :S

Comment: also re-adding JSON.stringify($scope.datiVeicolo) the object passed is null, i try to put also Serializable object but still null on the ApiController.

Comment: because it is not PARAMS!